# How can we peek through to find the next value and when it occured?

Tags: sql, oracle, hierarchy, audit, analytical

I have a audit table that records the value of each field with the timestamp of the change. I want to write a query that takes a start value for a column, peek through to find when that value changed and in the same record give me the timestamp of the change.

Is this possible?

I have tried to explore using LEAD() function and then a hierarchical query so far to no avail.

Here are what i tried with the LEAD().

```
 SELECT provider_id,
            sub_address_id,
            flag_practice,
            flag_mailing,

            last_updated_db_date,
            LEAD (
               flag_practice)
            OVER (PARTITION BY provider_id, sub_provider_address_id
                  ORDER BY last_updated_db_date ASC)
               next_flag_practice,
            LEAD (
               flag_mailing)
            OVER (PARTITION BY provider_id, sub_provider_address_id
                  ORDER BY last_updated_db_date ASC)
               next_flag_mailing,

            LEAD (
               last_updated_db_date)
            OVER (
               PARTITION BY provider_id, sub_provider_address_id
               ORDER BY last_updated_db_date ASC)
               next_practice_update_date, --this does not necessarily produce the next update date of the PRACTICE field but rather any update (which i dont want)

            RANK ()
            OVER (PARTITION BY provider_id, sub_provider_address_id
                  ORDER BY last_updated_db_date ASC)
               rnk -- thought it might help in some form later, haven't quite seen how yet
       FROM aud_address
   ORDER BY provider_id, sub_provider_address_id, rnk;
```

Comment: Sample data and expected result would help.

Answer (score 0):

I made some assumptions about your data since you didn't provide any test data but please correct if wrong.  Basically, I think the rank field was causing some weird results.  When I run this, I'm able to get the results that I would expect (not last_updated_date across multiple provider ID's - only for a single provider/subprovider combination).

```
    WITH aud_address AS (
        SELECT 108 provider_id, 216 sub_provider_address_id, 1 flag_practice, 0 flag_mailing, to_date('01/03/2014','mm/dd/yyyy') last_updated_db_date FROM DUAL
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 108 provider_id, 216 sub_provider_address_id, 0 flag_practice, 0 flag_mailing, to_date('01/06/2014','mm/dd/yyyy') last_updated_db_date FROM DUAL
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 108 provider_id, 253 sub_provider_address_id, 0 flag_practice, 1 flag_mailing, to_date('01/18/2014','mm/dd/yyyy') last_updated_db_date FROM DUAL
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 108 provider_id, 253 sub_provider_address_id, 1 flag_practice, 1 flag_mailing, to_date('01/13/2014','mm/dd/yyyy') last_updated_db_date FROM DUAL
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 136 provider_id, 345 sub_provider_address_id, 1 flag_practice, 0 flag_mailing, to_date('02/13/2014','mm/dd/yyyy') last_updated_db_date FROM DUAL
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 136 provider_id, 321 sub_provider_address_id, 0 flag_practice, 0 flag_mailing, to_date('02/12/2014','mm/dd/yyyy') last_updated_db_date FROM DUAL
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 136 provider_id, 321 sub_provider_address_id, 1 flag_practice, 1 flag_mailing, to_date('02/18/2014','mm/dd/yyyy') last_updated_db_date FROM DUAL
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 136 provider_id, 345 sub_provider_address_id, 0 flag_practice, 1 flag_mailing, to_date('02/17/2014','mm/dd/yyyy') last_updated_db_date FROM DUAL
    )
    SELECT provider_id,
                sub_provider_address_id,
                flag_practice,
                flag_mailing,
                last_updated_db_date,
                LEAD (
                   flag_practice)
                OVER (PARTITION BY provider_id, sub_provider_address_id
                      ORDER BY last_updated_db_date ASC)
                   next_flag_practice,
                LEAD (
                   flag_mailing)
                OVER (PARTITION BY provider_id, sub_provider_address_id
                      ORDER BY last_updated_db_date ASC)
                   next_flag_mailing,

                LEAD (
                   last_updated_db_date)
                OVER (
                   PARTITION BY provider_id, sub_provider_address_id
                   ORDER BY last_updated_db_date ASC)
                   next_practice_update_date
           FROM aud_address
       ORDER BY provider_id, sub_provider_address_id,last_updated_db_date;
```